# Implied vol bounded if and only if instantaneous vol bounded

Tags: options, implied-volatility, arbitrage, stochastic-volatility, no-arbitrage-theory

I'd like to show that in diffusion models IV is bounded iff instantaneous vol is bounded if there is to be no arbitrage. So, assume a model under the pricing measure of the form
$$
dS_u = \sigma_u S_u dW_u,
$$
where the notation $\sigma_u$ means any local stochastic volatility.

I am going to assume first that $\forall{u}\in[0,T] \;m\leq\sigma_u \leq M$. Suppose then that $I_0(K,T)$ is the IV at $t=0$ for the vanilla option with strike $K$ and maturity $T$. Then delta hedging the option to maturity **always** using the initial IV $I_0(K,T)$ gives the following (well-known) terminal P/L at maturity date $T$:
$$
P/L (T) = \frac12 \int_0^T \Gamma^{BS}_u(I_0(K,T),K)S_u^2 \left[I_0^2(K,T) - \sigma^2_u \right] \,du
$$
with $\Gamma^{BS}_u(I_0(K,T),K)$ the BS gamma at time $u$ with fixed IV $I_0(K,T)$. Assume that $I_0(K,T) > M$. Then a sure profit will be made under all scenarios, which contradicts no arbitrage. Hence $I_0(K,T) \leq M$.

All the other proofs follow exactly the same reasoning.

My question: is the proof above correct, have I overlooked something? Is there another/shorter/better proof?

**EDIT:**
Showing that instantaneous vol is bounded if IV is bounded ($m \leq I_0(K,T) \leq M$) is actually less straightforward. Invoking the delta hedging argument above will only show that $\exists u \in [0,T]$ such that $m\leq\sigma_u\leq M$, but not necessarily $\forall u\in [0,T]$.

I think a further restriction needs to be placed on the IVs. The correct statement is I believe
$$ 
\exists K\; \forall u\in [0,T]\; m \leq I_u(K,T) \leq M \Rightarrow \forall u\in [0,T]\; m \leq\sigma_u \leq M
$$

But this is a condition that cannot I think readily be obtained from the vanilla smile.

Comment: How do you handle the only-if part?

Comment: @KurtG. Good point, thanks. See my edit.

Comment: '@FridoRolloos' .  I am thinking of this counter example. Let $\sigma_t$ be deterministic and unbounded: $\sigma_t=|1-t|^{-\alpha}$ with $0<\alpha<1/2\,.$ then $\int_0^T\sigma^2_t\,dt$ is finite for all $T\,,$ hence the stochastic integral is defined. On a finite interval $[0,T]$ the implied vols are bounded (beause they equal $I(K,T)=\sqrt{\int_0^T\sigma^2_t\,dt/T}\,.$)

Comment: @KurtG. What is $x$ in your (counter)example?

Comment: Sorry I mean $t$. $\sigma_t$ has a pole at $t=1$.

Comment: @KurtG. Have given your counterexample some more thought. It is correct of course what you say, hence the instantaneous vol can be unbounded on sets of measure zero.

Comment: It looks like implied volatiliy is a huge field of research in itself. Have just found this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06812.pdf). There is more when you google for 'asymptotics of implied volatility'. Jim Gatheral has written a whole book on the volatility surface (haven't looked into it yet).